# input:focus to change an other div

Tags: html, css, input-field

I would like to select my input field and that the paragraph I put inside the input field moves up. So when I have `input:focus` I'd like `.tekstenveld p` to move up.

I am trying to recreate something I have seen on codrops about creative input fields but I can't figure out how they can select one thing and with that moving something else.

[Here is the link](http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index2.html) to the creative input fields so you can get an understanding what I mean.

Here is what I have tried so far in [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ho0qsyb6/1/)

```css
input {
  height: 65px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 100;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #D11E1F;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}

.tekstenveld {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.tekstenveld p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 50;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tekstenveld input:focus p {
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tekstenveld">
  <p>Example text</p>
  <input type="text" class="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam">
</div>
```

Comment: Use semantic markup. Change your `<p>` to `<label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate a pure css effect on `:focus` you need to switch first the order between the paragraph and the input. Then the css rule should be

```
.tekstenveld input:focus + p {
  ...
}
```

perhaps with a short css `transition` applied over the `bottom` property to make it nicer:

```
p {
   ...
   transition: bottom .5s;
}
```

(Be sure to have enough room for the paragraph when it moves above the `input` element)

Here's the final result: https://jsfiddle.net/0y9k50e5/1/

---

If you need to also keep the text above the input when it is filled you might add a `required` attribute to the `input` and change the style like so

```
.tekstenveld input:focus + p,
.tekstenveld input:valid + p {
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/0y9k50e5/2/
(Note: this method works on IE10+)

Comment: I have an other question though... If I fill in my input with text and I click somewhere else the focus isn't on the input anymore naturally. So now the text that floated above now collides with the entered text.

How can I make it so that it stays floating above the input field when text is entered?

Comment: see my update, it's a css only approach but it requires IE10+. Otherwise you need to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and let me know :)

```css
input {
  height: 65px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 100;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #D11E1F;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}

.tekstenveld {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.tekstenveld p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 50;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tekstenveld input:focus + p {
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tekstenveld">
  <input type="text" class="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam">
  <p>Example text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes your method is the same as the one above and it works! So thank you very much. :)